# Size of stack and Value Types

Tags: c#, .net

Lets say that we have a local variable of value type (struct for example). It would exist in the stack. But the size of struct can be different (8 bytes,800 bytes or 8 Mbytes theriotically).

What happens when the size of value type is greater than stack size?

Comment: For reference, AFAIK C# doesn't allow variable-sized structs.  If the struct gives the appearance of being different sizes, it probably contains a reference-type that holds at least some of the actual data.

Comment: the size is constant. different types - different sizes

Comment: Ahh.. that makes a bit more sense :)

Comment: I find it kind of funny that someone on Stack Overflow doesn't know what stack overflow is.

Comment: Pretty much the only way to get a stack overflow is a deeply recursive function. In most cases having a bug that triggers infinite recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StackOverflowException is thrown when the execution stack overflows. Microsoft recommends never create value types bigger then 16 bytes.

Comment: The recommendation isn't so much because of the risk of overflowing the stack as it is because, by default, structs are copied every time they're assigned or passed to a function -- and copying more bytes takes more time.  Still, it's a very good recommendation.

Comment: Yes, this is why string is a reference type

Answer (score 2):

> Lets say that we have a local variable of value type. Storage will be allocated on the temporary pool, which is typically implemented by allocating off the stack.  What happens when the size of the storage required to store all the local variables is greater than available stack space?

You get an "out of stack" exception. I am curious: what other behaviour were you imagining might happen when you run out of stack?

Comment: well, there could be some kind of wrapper to store the data on the heap or compiler error. That was a lack of my knowledge and I didn't find answer before the stackoverflow

Comment: @YuriyVikulov: If you know you won't have space on the stack, you certainly can store the value on the heap instead -- there are a variety of ways.  You can box it into an `object`, or make it a member of some reference type, but a better way is to make an array of the value type, as arrays never go on the stack.  But the compiler will not make this decision for you.

Comment: I do understand that it is an ugly style to have 8Mb struct and do understand solutions you gave. That was theriotical question cause of my curiosity.

Comment: I think StackOverflow should automatically downvote any comment about stack overflows that doesn't use the term stack overflow...